# Execute commands using function calls in shell scripts

Tags: function, shell

I am trying to execute a command using function calls in a shell script. When I pass the command to that function as an argument of that function, it does not work.

Function definition:

```
function ExecuteCommand() (

    # $1: User@Host
    # $2: Password
    # $3: Command to execute

    # Collect current IFS value
    OLD_IFS=$IFS

    # Set IFS value to new line feed
    IFS=$'\n'

    #Execute the command and capture the output
    EXPECT_OUTPUT=($(expect ssh_exec.expect $1 $2 $3))

    #Print the output
    OUTPUT_LINE_COUNT=${#EXPECT_OUTPUT[@]}
    for ((OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX=0; OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX<OUTPUT_LINE_COUNT; OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX++)) ;
    do
            echo ${EXPECT_OUTPUT[$OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX]}
    done

    # Get back to the original IFS 
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

)

Function call:

```
ExecuteCommand oracle@192.168.***.*** password123 "srvctl status database -d mydb"
```

And the output I get is:

```
spawn ssh oracle@192.168.***.*** {srvctl status database -d mydb}
oracle@192.168.***.***'s password: 
bash: {srvctl: command not found
```

But when I don't pass the command as an argument of the function, it works perfectly:

Function definition in that case:

```
function ExecuteCommand() (

    # $1: User@Host
    # $2: Password

    # Collect current IFS value
    OLD_IFS=$IFS

    # Set IFS value to new line feed
    IFS=$'\n'

    #Execute the command and capture the output
    EXPECT_OUTPUT=($(expect ssh_exec.expect $1 $2 srvctl status database -d mydb))

    #Print the output
    OUTPUT_LINE_COUNT=${#EXPECT_OUTPUT[@]}
    for ((OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX=0; OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX<OUTPUT_LINE_COUNT; OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX++)) ;
    do
            echo ${EXPECT_OUTPUT[$OUTPUT_LINE_INDEX]}
    done

    # Get back to the original IFS 
    IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

)

Function call:

```
ExecuteCommand oracle@192.168.***.*** password123
```

And I get the output just as I expected:

```
spawn ssh oracle@192.168.***.*** srvctl status database -d mydb
oracle@192.168.***.***'s password: 
Instance mydb1 is running on node mydb1
Instance mydb2 is running on node mydb2
Instance mydb3 is running on node mydb3
```

Please help me about what was wrong while passing the command as a function parameter here in the first case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong, any argument to "expect" within double quotes gets replaced with curly braces. Hence, the expect command became like:

```
expect ssh_exec.expect oracle@192.168.***.*** {srvctl status database -d mydb}
```

which made the shell to interpret "{srvctl" as a command.

Try using it like this:

```
EXPECT_OUTPUT=($(expect ssh_exec.expect $*))
```

instead of

```
EXPECT_OUTPUT=($(expect ssh_exec.expect $1 $2 $3))
```

And call your function like:

```
ExecuteCommand oracle@192.168.***.*** password123 srvctl status database -d mydb
```